# Put value in different hashmap according to condition

Tags: java, hashmap

I have these 3 functions mentioned below the only difference in these functions are the different hashmaps, can I make it a single function and from the redefineHeaderParameters I got the name of the hashmap and put key-value dynamically

```
public void redefineHeaderParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {
    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        headerParameters.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        headerParameters.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        headerParameters.put(parameterName, null);
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        headerParameters.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
        
    }
}

public void redefineQueryParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {

    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        queryParameters.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        queryParameters.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        queryParameters.put(parameterName, null);
        System.out.println(queryParameters);

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        queryParameters.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
    
    }
}

public void redefineBodyParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {

    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        bodyParameters.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        bodyParameters.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        bodyParameters.put(parameterName, null);
        
    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        bodyParameters.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, just have one function and add the HashMap as another parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tgdavies mentioned in the comment, you could pass the map to the method:

```
public void redefineParameters(HashMap<String, String> map, String condition, String parameterName) {
    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        map.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        map.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        map.put(parameterName, null);

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        map.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
    }
}
```

Or, make the generic method private and have named wrappers:

```
public void redefineHeaderParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {
    redefineParameters(headerParameters, condition, parameterName);
}

public void redefineQueryParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {
    redefineParameters(queryParameters, condition, parameterName);
}

public void redefineBodyParameters(String condition, String parameterName) {
    redefineParameters(bodyParameters, condition, parameterName);
}

private void redefineParameters(Map<String, String> map, String condition, String parameterName) {

    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        map.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        map.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        map.put(parameterName, null);

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        map.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
    }
}
```

Another alternative, if the maps are not in scope for the caller, is to pass another parameter to indicate which type of parameter it is:

```
public enum ParameterType { HEADER, QUERY, BODY };

public void redefineParameters(ParameterType parameterType, String condition, String parameterName) {
    Map<String, String> map;
    switch (parameterType) {
        case HEADER:
            map = headerParameters;
            break;
        case QUERY:
            map = queryParameters;
            break;
        case BODY:
            map = bodyParameters;
            break;
    }
    if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid")) {
        map.put(parameterName, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("incorrect")) {
        map.put(parameterName, correctParameter.get(parameterName).replaceAll(
                correctParameter.get(parameterName).substring(2, 7), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5)));

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        map.put(parameterName, null);

    } else if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expired") || condition.equalsIgnoreCase("expire")) {
        map.put(parameterName, expiredParameter.get(parameterName));
    }
}
```